# Is it possible to host a Monero node on a MBP w/ Ubuntu VM, while currently running XMRig on host?

Tags: monerod, macos

Currently I'm running MyMonero Wallet and XMRig on my MBP connected to a mining pool. Now I'd like to setup a Monero node as well on the same machine.

From what I've read from various sources from Reddit, it appears I should use Monero GUI Wallet, so I presume I need to get that and I can't my MyMonero Wallet anymore?

Also, I am getting the idea that to host a Monero node, it's only done on a Linux box. I run VM software (Parallels) on the Mac, and have Ubuntu 18.04.5 Desktop as a VM. Can I run Ubuntu as a VM and use it as a Monero Node Host? Do I have to get the Ubuntu Server, and also ok to run as a VM?

Can the Monero node be hosted on the Mac?

Is there a quick and easy set by step video for a machine and setup like mine somewhere? I can't find what I need specifically on Youtube.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to host a Monero node on a MBP w/ Ubuntu VM, while currently running XMRig on host?

Yes. But you can run a Monero node directly on the Mac without the need for a Ubuntu VM.

> so I presume I need to get that and I can't my MyMonero Wallet anymore?

You can use *both* the official Monero GUI and unofficial MyMonero wallet on the same machine if you want to.

> Also, I am getting the idea that to host a Monero node, it's only done on a Linux box.

Wrong. You can run a Monero node directly on a Mac. You **do not** need to run it in a Linux VM.

> Can I run Ubuntu as a VM and use it as a Monero Node Host?

Yes. But you don't need to, see above point.

> Do I have to get the Ubuntu Server, and also ok to run as a VM?

You do not have and do not need to, see above point.

> Can the Monero node be hosted on the Mac?

Yes. Mac release downloads can be found at both https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/ and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases

> Is there a quick and easy set by step video...

There are dozens of videos and tutorials online for running Monero, all of debatable usefulness. Simply downloading and running the Monero GUI also runs a Monero "node".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. From what I'm reading on the links you posted, that is using a local node to mine the block and feed your own wallet, and is a GUI local to your machine todo all that. What I'm looking for, and I wasn't being clear previously as I'm a newbie and I'm learning, I'm looking to host a full Monero Node, for public, or maybe hidden (Tor), for others to use. As a way to help support Monero, and earn rewards. I thought I read on Reddit about 9 months ago, there there was a 'kit' in the works, to make getting this up and running more straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: "I'm looking to host a full Monero Node, for public, or maybe hidden (Tor), for others to use." <- Hosting a full node on a *laptop* is not going to be much help to others unless you keep it running 24/7, with a fast network connection, forwarded ports. If your goal is to help others by hosting a node, the simplest way is to rent a VPS, install Monero and keep it running. "I thought I read on Reddit about 9 months ago, there there was a 'kit' in the works" <- No idea what you're referring to.